# Enabled links from a given media entity

Tags: mediacontroller, v4l2

In Linux V4L2 and media controller architecture, we treat media devices as media entities and establish connections between them dynamically on the go..!! For example, demux0(demuxer 0) can be connected to Vid_plane1(Entity name given to the main video output). Also One media entity can be connected with multiple media entities at a time.

My question is if i want to find out how many enabled connections are existing from a particular media entities output pad(Sink pad), what is the method to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media-ctl utility, which will enumerate all v4l2 entities in specified  media controller.

One thing you should pay attention to is the difference between target kernel version of media/v4l2 header file and header definitions in media-ctl utility.

http://git.ideasonboard.org/media-ctl.git

Comment: Thanks. I actually did the same thing..!!